# Let$ K$ be a finite extension of $F$. If $L_1,L_2$ are subfields of $K$ containing $F$ and $L_1⊂ L_2$ then $K$ is simple extension of $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have seen this problem in field note , but I can not do this.
Let $K$ be a finite extension of $F$ such that for every pair $L_1,L_2$ of subfields of $K$ containing $F$, either $L_1⊂ L_2$ or $L_2⊂ L_1$. Show that $K$ is a simple extension of $F$.

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate fields are linearly ordered by inclusion meaning that there exist at most one field of each degree (because if $E_1 \subseteq E_2$ and $[E_1:F]=[E_2:F]$ we get $E_1=E_2$).

Since $K/F$ is finite, there are only finitely many intermediate fields and they are linearly ordered by inclusion, so there is a maximal such field, i. e. a proper subfield $L\subsetneq K$ that contains all the intermediate fields. Then $K=F(\alpha) $ for any $\alpha \in K\setminus L$.

Comment: I can not under stand why K=F(α). Please, explain the steps of the comments .

Comment: $F(\alpha)$ is an intermediate field $F\subseteq F(\alpha) \subseteq K$ so, by the choice of $L$, either $K(\alpha)\subseteq L$ or $K=F(\alpha)$. The first option is impossible since $\alpha\notin L$.

Comment: I realised now that my explanation of the fact there are finitely many intermediate fields was lacking, so I added a correct proof of this.